# How to build projects in solution using DTE?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, envdte, vs-extensibility

I have three projects in solution and trying to build all the projects in solution by below code.

But it builds startup project alone.

`var solutionBuilder = dte.Solution.SolutionBuild;`

`solutionBuilder.Build(true);`

solutionBuilder.StartupProjects.Count returns one. There is no info about 3 projects in SolutionBuilder instance.

Is there any other way to build all the projects in solution?

Comment: You should look at this thread, it helped me.

[how-to-get-notification-when-a-successful-build-has-finished][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801985/how-to-get-notification-when-a-successful-build-has-finished

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to know, if the projects have dependencies between each other.

If all else fails, you could always use something like this

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution","")
```