# Visual Studio 2013 Automation: How can I tell whether a solution needs to be built (meaning, a change was made since last build)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, automation, build-automation, visual-studio-addins

How can I tell whether a solution needs to be built (meaning, a change was made since last build)? I use the [Solution4 Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte100.solution4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This related question has the answer you need, with examples

[How to get notification when a successful build has finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801985/how-to-get-notification-when-a-successful-build-has-finished)

"to figure out when a successful build has finished, you need to use a combination of the two build events:

OnBuildProjConfigDone and OnBuildDone"

In addition, you can also use

[Solution4.Saved property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231193.aspx)

to check if the solution has changed since last successful build.

You should assume that on open, a solution needs to be built.

Comment: Nope. `Solution4.Saved` is never `true`, have no idea why - whether I change any `*.cs` file without saving it, or change and then save it - it just doesn't change. Same thing with every `EnvDTE.Project` object in my solution: `EnvDTE.Project.Saved` is always `true`, no matter what I do, and `EnvDTE.Project.IsDirty` is always `false`, again, whatever I try. Any idea?